# Import package & type

Tags: go

Here is my problem and my project structure

```
src
|-->config
       |--> config.go
|-->otherPackage
       |--> otherFile.go
|-->main.go
```

I have a type on `config.go` that I would like to use in `otherFile.go`

But when I tried to add it to the import here theses issues:

1. `imported and not used.`
2. `undefined: Config`

Although I use it in the function declaration

`function(target float64, entries [2]float64, config Config)`

What is the problem with this?

I tried to import it with

```
import (
    "fmt"
    "math"
    "../config"
)
```

Comment: how do you import it?

Comment: @mic4ael with the import, i just edit my post for awnsering to your question

Comment: The first thing you should read is [How to Write Go Code](https://golang.org/doc/code.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot "import *from* a package". All you can do is "import the *whole* package". That means if you `import "full/import/path/of/foo"` and that package declared itself to be called foo via `package foo` at the beginning, then everything in this package has to be qualified by `foo`:

```
foo.Config
```

If you package is called `config` than declaring a variable `config` will shaddow the whole package: so you have to:

1. Rename the config variable to e.g. `cfg`
2. Reference Config from package config with its qualified name `config.Config`

Comment: Sorry, i didn't understand well. I just have to rename the variable on my otherFile or on the config.go file ?

Comment: @kevingiroux you can do this `import cfg "path/to/config"`. You can then refer to that package as `cfg` i.e. `cfg.Config`, `cfg.Var1`, `cfg.Var2`, etc.

Comment: The best advice is: Work through the Tour of Go once more. Then read some other packages and understand what's going on. You'll have to build understanding, not apply mechanical fixes.

Comment: It seems to be another problem, my GoPath is not well configured. When i try echo $GOPATH i have $Home/Document/workspace/go
But i search on $Home/go ...

Comment: Then read How to Write Go Code and _stick_ to it _word_ _for_ _word_.